# Issue with elixir-phoenix-on-google-compute-engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, elixir, google-compute-engine, phoenix-framework

I’m trying to deploy to GCP Compute Engine by following this tutorial
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/elixir-phoenix-on-google-compute-engine

Unable to connect to provided external IP after create firewall-rules
There are no errors in following the tutorial. But cannot connect to `http://${external_ip}:8080` after creating firewall rules

Build release is already in Google Cloud Storage

I copy `hello`

```
gsutil cp _build/prod/rel/hello/bin/hello\
    gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/hello-release
```

instead of `hello.run`

```
gsutil cp _build/prod/rel/hello/bin/hello.run \
    gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/hello-release
```

My `instance-startup.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex
export HOME=/app
mkdir -p ${HOME}
cd ${HOME}

RELEASE_URL=$(curl \
  -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/release-url" \
  -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
gsutil cp ${RELEASE_URL} hello-release
chmod 755 hello-release

wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 \
  -O cloud_sql_proxy
chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy

mkdir /tmp/cloudsql
PROJECT_ID=$(curl \
  -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" \
  -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
./cloud_sql_proxy -projects=${PROJECT_ID} -dir=/tmp/cloudsql &

PORT=8080 ./hello-release start
```

`gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output` shows

```
...
Feb 23 18:02:35 hello-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script: + PORT=8080 ./hello-release start
Feb 23 18:02:35 hello-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script: + ./cloud_sql_proxy -projects= hello -dir=/tmp/cloudsql
Feb 23 18:02:35 hello-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script: 2019/02/23 18:02:35 Rlimits for file descriptors set to {&{8500 8500}}
Feb 23 18:02:35 hello-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script: ./hello-release: 31: exec: /app/hello_rc_exec.sh: not found
Feb 23 18:02:39 hello-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script: 2019/02/23 18:02:39 Listening on /tmp/cloudsql/hello:asia-east1:hello-db/.s.PGSQL.5432 for hello:asia-east1: hello-db
Feb 23 18:02:39 hello-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script: 2019/02/23 18:02:39 Ready for new connections
Feb 23 18:08:08 hello-instance ntpd[656]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized
```

`hello_rc_exec.sh` is generated after initialize Distillery. It is stored in `_build/prod/rel/hello/bin/hello_rc_exec.sh`

`firewall rules`

```
NAME                     NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW        DENY  DISABLED
default-allow-http-8080  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:8080           False
...
```

I also run in `ps aux | grep erl` in the instance

```
hello_team@hello-instance:~$ ps aux | grep erl
hello_t+ 23166  0.0  0.0  12784  1032 pts/0    S+   08:04   0:00 grep erl
```

Im not sure what information is needed to fix this

Please do ask for information and I will provide them.
Thank you

Comment: `Enable billing for your project.` --  No thanks.

Comment: @7stud hahaha. they give you 300$ for 1 year for free. So you can use that to do development or just give it a try

Comment: *You must provide credit card or bank details to set up a billing account to verify your identity...* -- It's a free trial, why do they need to know who I am? :(

Comment: @7stud I dont know. Same goes to AWS. previously AWS did not ask for credit card details. But now, in registration, you need to include credit card details. I guess because people stop paying after they receive the bill and create a new account? Hahaha

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on which issue you want addressed, can you clearly state your question?

Comment: I cannot connect to the external IP of the instance. I'm not sure what I did wrong. I think I follow everything from the tutorial correctly

Comment: I believe you need to verify followed steps again. Did you whitelist your IP address as explained in the doc? Is your Cloud SQL proxy run when you start it? Are you using the same tag when you create the instance which is 'http-server'? Also, there is possibility any other firewall rule is preventing to communicate with external IP address. And are you able to [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) to the created instance? If so, run this command in your instance to make sure services are listening and they're not block: **netstat -plnt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [here](https://elixirforum.com/t/deployment-to-google-compute-engine/20409).

Thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here was the solution ([worked out in this forum thread](https://elixirforum.com/t/deployment-to-google-compute-engine/20409)).

First, the poster had uploaded the `hello` file instead of `hello.run` to cloud storage. The tutorial intentionally specifies uploading `hello.run` because it is a full executable archive of the entire release, whereas `hello` is merely a wrapper script and is by itself not capable of executing the app. So this modification to the procedure needed to be reverted.

Second, the poster's app included the `elixir_bcrypt` library. This library includes a NIF whose platform-specific binary code is built in the `deps` directory (instead of the `_build` directory). The tutorial's procedure doesn't properly clean out binaries in `deps` prior to cross-compiling for deployment, and so the poster's macOS-built bcrypt library was leaking into the build. When deployed to compute engine on Debian, this crashed on initialization. The poster fixed this problem by deleting the `deps` directory and re-installing dependencies while cross-compiling.

It was also noted during the discussion that the tutorial promoted a poor practice of mounting the user's app in a volume when doing a Docker cross-compilation. Instead, it should simply copy the app into the image, perform the entire build there, and use `docker cp` to extract the built artifact. This practice would have prevented this issue. A [work item](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/issues/774) was filed to modify the tutorial accordingly.